# How to fix runtime error 91 on SQL Query?

Tags: excel, vba

This code requests two input variables from the user and then uses those variables in a query to return data from internal company software. I adapted this code from a macro that someone else at the company uses without issue.

My macro:

- Compiles without issue
- Experiences run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

  - Occurs at `With.Selection.ListObject.QueryTable`

NOTE: Some details e.g. company name, server, login etc removed!

```
Option Explicit

Public EN As String
Public REV As String
Dim SearchString As String
Dim SearchString1 As String
Dim SearchString2 As String


Public Sub QueryImport()

EN = Import_Details.EN.Value
REV = Import_Details.REV.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Unload Import_Details

SearchString = EN
SearchString = EN & Chr(37)
SearchString = EN & Chr(47) & REV & Chr(37)

Sheets("Import").Range("A2").Select

With Selection.ListObject.QueryTable
     .Connection = _
    "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=XXXXXX-       XX;UID=XX;PWD=XXXXXX;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=XXXX;DATABASE=XXX-Live"
    .CommandText = _
    "SELECT Enquirys_list_with_Parts.""Item No"", Enquirys_list_with_Parts.Description, Enquirys_list_with_Parts.""Part No"", Enquirys_list_with_Parts.Qty, Enquirys_list_with_Parts.Price, Enquirys_list_with_Parts.Total" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "FROM ""Emax-Live"".dbo.ENQUIRY_LINES_LIST ENQUIRY_LINES_LIST, ""Emax-Live"".dbo.Enquirys_list_with_Parts Enquirys_list_with_Parts, ""Emax-Live"".dbo.Quote_Line_Qty_Drop_list Quote_Line_Qty_Drop_list" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "WHERE Enquirys_list_with_Parts.""Enquiry No"" = ENQUIRY_LINES_LIST.""Enquiry No"" AND Enquirys_list_with_Parts.""Part No"" = Quote_Line_Qty_Drop_list.Part_No AND ENQUIRY_LINES_LIST.Enquiry_Line_id = Enquirys_list_with_Parts.Enquiry_Line_id AND ((Enquirys_list_with_Parts.""Enquiry No"" Like '" & SearchString1 & "' And Enquirys_list_with_Parts.""Enquiry No"" Like '" & SearchString & "') AND (Quote_Line_Qty_Drop_list.""Quote No"" Like '" & SearchString2 & "'))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
    "ORDER BY Enquirys_list_with_Parts.""Item No""" _

    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid using Select and Selection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference an object that was never set.

```
Dim MyQueryTbl as QueryTable

Set MyQueryTbl = Sheet1.QueryTables(1)
```

Then you can manipulate your MyQueryTbl object.